# Transistor to disconnect Ethernet connection

Tags: relay, ethernet

An old notebook I found in the basement always tries to boot from the network as I start it. Unfortunately I've forgotten the BIOS password.

I figured out that one USB port delivers power until Windows has booted. My idea was to cut the Ethernet connection with the power of this USB port. As I read I just have to cut the wire of pin 6 with a relay.

As all of the relays I have laying around need 7 V to work, I wonder if I could use a transistor as well, but as I am not too familiar with transistors, I am not sure how to do this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The problem with doing this is ethernet is impedance controlled, so running it through a relay will change the impedance and cause noise and packet loss. A better way would be to take off the bottom cover of the laptop, find the bios battery and unplug it for 30 seconds to reset the bios

Comment: I already tried to put out the bios battery but it didn't worked. I read this trick is not working on some devices maybe it's like this here.

Comment: I take it that you're trying to avoid the long delay while the laptop times out waiting for a nonexistent network boot server. Why can't you just wait to plug in the Ethernet cable until after Windows has booted from the local drive?

Comment: Did you wait five minutes before reseating the battery.

Comment: That is how I am doing it right now but I am using a dockinstation, and a separated monitor so I always have to put the laptop out of the dockingstation, start it and put it back in. This is not a really elegant way.

Comment: No I think I waited round about two minutes. You think this was to short?

Comment: Make sure you take out the main battery, the bios battery and the power cord

Comment: I dont think a relay is a good idea, but I dont see how a relay requiring 7 volts can be driven by 5 volts + transistor. Transistors amplify weak signals but do not boost maximum voltages (you need caps and/or coils for that, possibly using transustors for the required oscillation)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to experiment with this USB powered relay idea you can get 5V relays, or USB cables that emit 12V [such as this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32954598655.html)